# How can i call the method from another class?

Tags: java, class, validation, methods

Hi i am trying to solve the problem I am facing

```
public class exam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1 a = new test1();
        
       }
    int zahl(int x, int y) {
        int e;
        if(x>y) {
            e=x-y;
        }else {
            e=y-x;
        }
        if(e==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int z=0;
        int i=1;
        while(i<=e) {
            z=z+i;
            i++;
        }
        return z;
    }

}
```

what I want to do is to call the zahl method to the test1 class

```
public class test1{
    private exam b;
    
    public void init() {
        b = new exam();
    }
    void test() {
        int result = b.zahl(2, 2);
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

}
```

this is what I have tried, but it returns nothing, even though it's supposed to show me error.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually executing the `test()` method?

Comment: @khelwood what does it mean? sorry i m new to java

Comment: I mean, you've shown us that there is a `test()` method that is asserting something about the result of `zahl`, but is `test()` being executed?

Comment: isn't it executed by defining the test() in main method?

Comment: No, it is not. You created an instance of your `test1` class, but you did not execute the `test()` method.

Comment: No, you created an instance of your class `test1` by invoking the automatically generated default constructor: `new test1();`. That's it. Nowhere did you actually **call** the method `test` for your instance: `a.test();`. Btw, you really should adhere to Java naming conventions and use clear and concise names for classes and methods. Otherwise it gets pretty confusing pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be declaring your functions with the `public` tag i.e. `public void test()` if you intend to access them from other functions outside of that package. The usual [Class naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) in Java is with capital first letter, which makes your code more readable for you and others.

For your question, I don't think you are actually invoking the `test()` method of the test1 class. If you want that method to get called every time, you could place it inside the default Constructor.